# Xcode 11.3.1 gives me No image found at path referenced under key CFBundleIcons appIconXX error when I try to validate my app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cfbundleicons

I am about to launch my ios app but when I do a **product**>**archive**>**validate app**
I get the errors "gives me No image found at path referenced under key CFBundleIcons" for all my icons
AppIcon20x20
AppIcon29x29
AppIcon40x40
AppIcon57x57
AppIcon60x60
etc

But I have added all icons in the AppIcon folder, also doubled checked that they are in the correct size and that all is .png But I keep getting the error.

My icons shows up in xcode's menu and in the simulator so its really weird

**contents.json**

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "size" : "20x20",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "40.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "20x20",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "60.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "29.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "58.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "87.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "80.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "120-1.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "57x57",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "57.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "57x57",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "114.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "120.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "180.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "1024x1024",
      "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
      "filename" : "1024.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: as idea - clear DerivedData folder and build again.

Comment: @VadimNikolaev The first thing I tried, but same result

Comment: do you have exactly 12 images with unique filenames + `Contents.json` file in AppIcon.appiconset?

Comment: @VadimNikolaev check the new printscreen of my folder and the content of content.json that I just updated

Comment: I don't understand why I have Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504), but I [haven't so many images](https://ibb.co/tZZdcXm). Deployment target is iOS11 for my app.